# NoReverseMatch Error in Django project: Bootstrap link causing problem? Can't see how or why though

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm really stumped on how to fix this. I've dealt with NoReverseMatch errors before and I'm aware that it's usually an issue with the URL path or the function related to it in views.py, but this particular page I'm trying to render keeps returning NoReverseMatch saying that there's a line in my layout.html template that contains my link to Bootstrap that's the problem. I've tried editing this line out but no good. I've checked the URL path and the relevant function in views.py but I can't see anything that suggests an error. Here's what I mean...

Error message

```
Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Leigh\Desktop\Coursework\CS50Web\project4\network\templates\network\layout.html, error at line 7

Reverse for 'register' not found. 'register' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here's an image of line 7 being referred to.

[image]

As I've mentioned, I've checked out line 160 in views.py which calls on the URL in urls.py.

Here is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "network"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("post", views.newpost, name="newpost"),
    path("post/<int:post_id>", views.post, name="post"),
    path("user/<int:user_id>", views.user, name="user"),
    path("following", views.following, name="following")
    
]
```

I'm at a loss really. I can't see anything that would be causing the NoReverseMatch. "register.html" definitely exists despite Django saying that there is no path, valid view/function/pattern name, etc.
Anyone out there a gun at Django on these sorts of things? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: did you use **include** with **namespace=".."** in your `urls.py` ?

Comment: Hi @AliAref what do you mean exactly bu include with namespace".."?

Comment: try using `your_app_name:register` instead of only `register` in reverse. as `return reverse("app_name:register")`

Comment: @AliAref do you mean in the url path?

Comment: @AliAref Just tried it out. It's returning a new AttributeError now. 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: may you show your `urls.py` file ?

Comment: @AliAref Sure, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232161/discussion-between-ali-aref-and-user14593966).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with bootstrap, One possible error could be that you haven't mentioned the app_name in the url.

Your urls.py:

```
app_name = "network"

    urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.index, name="index"),
        path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
        path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
        path("register", views.register, name="register"),
        path("post", views.newpost, name="newpost"),
        path("post/<int:post_id>", views.post, name="post"),
        path("user/<int:user_id>", views.user, name="user"),
        path("following", views.following, name="following")
        
    ]
```

Then the html file should have:

```
correct: {% url 'network:register' %}
incorrect {% url 'register'%}
```

We are just linking the bootstrap to our html file and hence it does not interfere with the url.